# zepto module in nodejs not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, zepto

I am a newbie with nodejs.

I installed globally modules zepto and jsdom :

```
npm install jsdom -g
npm install zepto -g
```

I checked with `npm list -g`. These modules are installed.

But when I reference these two modules in a script using require:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");
var Zepto = require("zepto");
```

I got an error message :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'zepto'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/user554/dev/exchange/bin/getExchangeData.js:6:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I tried with only jsdom and only zepto. Only Zepto fails.

What am I missing ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: To `require()` a module, install it [locally](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders). Global packages are only meant to be used from the command-line. If you need both uses, you'll have to install it in both locations. Docs: [`npm-folders`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/files/npm-folders.html).

Comment: Thank but it doesn't seems to fit my need. I want to use node.js in many scripts with same modules. So it is insane to maintain many copies of same files.

Comment: The localized installations are generally for version dependencies over just the module as a whole. NPM only installs one version of a module in a given path. By using the global module in each application, you may have to modify all applications at once to support updating the module, or have to hold off if even one simply can't support the update.

Comment: I understand your point. But what do you think to install it locally only when compatibility issue occurs. Until this day, it will be easier to maintain. Regarding the module I use and the way I use them, it should be a very long time before there is no retro compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zepto` package is not a proper Node package. It installs a minified version of the Zepto lib, but it looks like it's meant for browser usage (why would it be in the NPM repository? I have no idea).

Instead, try the [`zepto-node`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/zepto-node) package.

Comment: Just to satisfy my curiosity, how do you know it is not a proper Node package ?

Comment: Because it doesn't load ;) But more seriously: the `package.json` file doesn't have a `main` property, which is used to point to an entry point that is loaded when you `require` a module.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that you're installing *globally*. Installing with `-g` is meant only for modules that provide some kind of command-line scripts (e.g. `express-generator` provides the `express` command that you can use from your shell prompt).

Generally you install the module without `-g` and it will get installed locally and you can `require()` it just fine. However, as pointed out by @robertklep, the `zepto` module currently [does not export anything](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/821d3b953fee57e0c3b1d1326b1b1d10c1f55932/package.json) (missing "lib" in package.json), so installing locally would not help for that particular module.

Comment: He can load `jsdom` (which is *also* installed globally) just fine, so that's not the problem. Installing the `zepto` package locally doesn't fix the problem either.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't fit my need to install it locally. Many scripts with same modules. That's why I am using globally installed modules and NODE_PATH.

Comment: Regarding `jsdom`, my guess is that they previously installed without `-g` or they used `npm link`, neither of which they shared in the original question.

Comment: @mscdex or `$NODE_PATH` is set such to allow loading global packages.

Comment: @mscdex NODE_PATH set properly do the job.

Comment: @robertklep maybe, but either way it wasn't mentioned originally. Also IMHO doing dependencies this way could eventually lead to problems and typically is considered bad design.

Comment: @mscdex I agree, but the issue here is mainly an incorrect package that's being used. Even installing it locally wouldn't have solved the problem.